# How to minimize a function where the number of variables is unknown?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a standard linear programming problems I want to solve:

$$ \min_x f^T x \text{ such that } \left\{ \begin{aligned} A\cdot x &\le b, \\ A_{eq}\cdot x &= b_{eq}, \\ lb \le x &\le ub. \end{aligned} \right. $$

$F^T$ is a vector that doesn't involve $x$.

The problem with the above minimization is that, I don't know what $n$, the number of variable $x$ is — it is also a part of the minimization. 
There are a few constraints governing how the vector $x$ should behave. Additionally, there are constraints linking from $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$. This means that given $x_i$, we know how to form the constraint for $x_{i+1}$. Also, even though we don't know about $n$, but in my problem I can easily construct the corresponding $f_i$ term for each $x_i$.

The constraints are complicated in the sense that it is not easy to express the constraints in the following form:

$$ Ax \leq a $$

and

$$ Bx = b $$

What I can do, at best, is to express $a$ and $b$ involving a first order of $x$ ( i.e., no $x^2$ and above). The matrix $A$ and $B$ are known values with no involvement of $x$.

I understand that linear programming can be used to tackle problems such as this. But the two problems I mention above ( don't know what $n$ is, and cannot separate out the matrix/vector easily) stop me from proceeding.

Is there any other techniques I can use to solve the problem?

Comment: May be you can have a look at the simplex method, Dual simplex method,...etc. They are the ones which i learnt when i studied this course, but now i have forgotten!

Comment: @Chandru1, as far as I know these methods require you to separate out the known matrix/vector values, which is not possible in my case.

Comment: Are the dimensions of $A$, $b$, or $f$ available?

Comment: @J. Mangaldan, that's the problem, the dimension of $f$ is tied to $x$, and hence it is also not available.

Comment: @J. Mangaldan, the dimension also not available. But $A$ and $b$ can be readily generated if we assume a particular value of $n$, namely the number of $x$ point.

Comment: Maybe just post the *actual* problem you have, and let the collective minds of this site wade through the thicket themselves?

Comment: @J. Mangaldan, give me sometime to prepare that ( I have great trouble typing mathematical notation!), or maybe I'll just start another question, since they are essentially different things

Comment: “What I can do, at best, is to express a and b involving a first order of x ( i.e., no x^2 and above).” This sounds like nothing but *nonlinear* optimization.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito, it is still linear, because through clever ( but maybe difficult!) rearranging you can have all the $x$ on the left hand side equation.

Comment: My point is that if the “linear” constraint itself varies depending on the value of the variables, it is no longer linear.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, note that $a$ and $b$ are the vectors, so if you do it carefully ( with some clever substitution), you can eliminate $x$ from $a$ and $b$. So your points don't apply

Comment: Ok, probably I do not understand your problem.

Comment: It has been a while. Could delayed column generation possibly solve your problem?

Comment: @WillemHagemann, would you like to explain how "delayed column generation" solves the problem?

Comment: I not really sure if delayed column generation is really capable to solve the problem. It was just an idea and I would need more information on the problem. How are the additional constraints on $x_{i+1}$ are generated? Is the number of rows in $A$ and $A_{eq}$ fixed?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe there are two ways to tackle this problem:

1. If the issue is just in the generation of the constraints $Ax \leq a$ and $Bx=b$, then these forms can be forced out using automatic differentiation.  Specifically, let $g(x) = Ax -a$ and $h(x) = Bx - b$.  To generate, $a$ and $b$, we evaluate $g(0)$ and $h(0)$, respectively.  In order to generate $A$ and $B$, take an arbitrary point $x$ and evaluate $g^\prime(x)$ and $h^\prime(x)$ using the Jacobian code from an available automatic differentiation toolbox to generate $A$ and $B$, respectively.  Even with a linear operator, it's sometimes easier to just use AD to generate them in the case that we have a matrix-free implementation of the operator.  Note, it's likely that the AD code will want to fix the number of variables, so this may not be the appropriate solution.  However, it depends on the code and the setup that you have.
2. Matrix-free implementations of an interior point method do not require the number of variables to be known.  Typically, they just require certain vector operations to be defined.  There may be a different list, but I typically work with

   - `init(x)` - Initialize memory
   - `copy(x)` - copy a vector
   - `scal(alpha,x)` - $\alpha x$
   - `axpy(alpha,x,y)` - $\alpha x + y$
   - `innr(x,y)` - $\langle x,y\rangle$
   - `prod(x,y)` - pointwise product
   - `linv(x,y)` - inverse of the pointwise product
   - `srch(x,y)` - how far we can go in the direction y form x till we violate nonnegativity
   - `barr(x)` - log-barrier function

Technically, we can generalize this to work with general symmetric cone constraints, but we should ignore that for now.  Anyway, none of these operations require the size of the vector to be defined as long as we can compute them.  Then, based on these operations, we have enough information to implement an interior point method to take care of the inequality constraints and an SQP method to take care of the equality constraints.  Now, candidly, if the number of variables is large, it's going to perform poorly.  Basically, there's a number of linear systems that need to be solved.  However, if the number of equality constraints is bigger than about 50 the Krylov methods used to solve these linear systems will start to deteriorate badly.  The way to get around this is to use a preconditioner, but without a matrix you're going to have to be very clever.  That'll depend on the problem structure.

In terms of existing codes and algorithms, [Optizelle](http://www.optimojoe.com/products/optizelle) can do this.  However, again, you really, really will need an effective preconditioner for the equality constraints in order to have a shot at making this work well.  Specifically, a preconditioner for $BB^T$.

As a final note, in general, for a linear program, you typically want to use a linear programming specific algorithm like a specialized primal-dual interior point method or the simplex method.  Typically, for the LP specific primal-dual interior point methods, you'll need to be able to take the Choleski factorization of a very particular system.  If you don't know the number of variables, this won't work.  That pushes you back to more general algorithms like those that [Optizelle](http://www.optimojoe.com/products/optizelle) uses.  That said, this code is not specialized for linear programs, so the performance will suffer.

Comment: "at about 50, Krylov methods will start to deteriorate badly": why 50 ($\pm$ 25) ? Are there simple but real examples that show this ?

Comment: @denis To be fair, this is just a rule of thumb, but one of the issues that comes up is lack orthogonality between the Krylov vectors over time.  A basic method will use something like Gram-Schmidt to orthogonalize vectors.  To get farther, we can use modified Gram-Schmidt or even a DGKS correction step, which is really just a fancy way to say orthogonalize twice.  Anyway, the easiest way to see this is to just code a basic method and then use something like `imagesc` in MATLAB/Octave to looks at `V'*V` where `V` are the Krylov vectors.  It should be the identity.  Eventually, it won't be.